# MaaS 2.0 - Reserve IP's

Tags: maas, cloud

A new "feature" of MaaS 2.0 is that it assumes total control of a Subnet. But I desperately need to reserve some IP's on the subnet that are currently in use. How can I achieve this with MaaS 2.0? Or do I need to downgrade to 1.9? If so, how can I specify to install version 1.9 on Ubuntu 16.04?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the API still supports this, I managed to exclude/reserve subnet ip's with the cli tool

`maas my-maas ipaddresses reserve ip_address=192.168.0.4`